# Java - merge two excel sheets into one

Tags: java, excel, merge

I need to merge two sheets into one.

Eg. I have excel file test.xls with two sheets, sheet0 and sheet1. Both sheets have some text and table.

I would like to merge them so merged sheet would look like this:

- text from sheet0
- table from sheet0
- text from sheet1
- table from sheet1

I need to do this in Java.

Is there a simple way to do this? 
Something like :

```
HSSFWorkbook book = new HSSFWorkbook("/tmp/test.xls");
HSSFSheet sheet0 = book.getSheetAt(0);
HSSFSheet sheet1 = book.getSheetAt(1);
sheet0.merge(sheet1); //or combine or something
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didn't find such method in Poi API

Otherwise, you can manually append the content of sheet1 into sheet0 like :

```
int lastRowNum1 = sheet1.getLastRowNum();

int i=0;
int currentLinePos=sheet0.getLastRowNum();
while ( i <= lastRowNum1 ){
    Row currentRow = sheet1.getRow(i++);
    Row copiedRow = sheet0.createRow(currentLinePos++);
    // code that copy the content of currentRow into copiedRow
    // such as copying every cells
    // or try copiedRow = currentRow; but not sure it will copy the cells
}
```